# how to export multiple files from python

Tags: python, file

I have several files and want to add some text to them (files are named as changed_1, changed_2, changed_3 and so on) in python. Here I copied a piece of my file:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 1 "volume_1"
$EndPhysicalNames
```

I want to add line/s exactly after the 3rd line (`3 1 "volume_1"`). I have another variable named as `n_iteration`. If `n_iteration` is 2, I want to add `3 2 "volume_2"` exactly after the 3rd line. If it is 3, I want to add `3 2 "volume_2"` and `3 3 "volume_3"` and so on. Finally I want to have my files changed and saved exactly like the input format but with these added lines (let's say `n_iteration = 4`):

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 1 "volume_1"
3 2 "volume_2"
3 3 "volume_3"
3 4 "volume_4"
$EndPhysicalNames
```

Point is that I want to do the same (adding these lines) for several files. I tried the following code but I was not successful. Firstly, it is doing the iteration over `n_iteration` rather than my files (it is making 4 outputs rather than `i` ones). I have three inputs but it is making four outputs which all are resulted from the last file (last `i` from the first for loop). It has also a problem for doing what I want (it adds new line differently in outputs):

```
from glob import glob
all_files = glob('changed_*')
for i in all_files:
    with open(i, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        n_iteration = 4
        for j in range(n_iteration,0,-1):
            with open('new'+ str (j), "w") as f:
                data.insert(2, ('3 ' + str(j) +' "volume_' + str(j) + '"\n'))
                del data[2+n_iteration]
                for c in data:
                    f.write(c)
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Comment: can you show us what the file looks like after the script runs

Comment: dear @Avi Baruch, files are .msh files and only contain simple text. But they have thousands of rows. I only showed here first four lines.

Comment: thats fine, just show the affected lines after so I can see what wrong

Comment: I did it for three files and wanted to add four lines (`n_iteration = 4`). It gave me four files, which are all exported from the last file imported to algorithm in the first for loop. the first file is completely OK. Second one= `$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 2 "volume_2"
3 3 "volume_3"
3 4 "volume_4"
3 1 "volume_1"`. Third one= `$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 3 "volume_3"
3 4 "volume_4"
3 1 "volume_1"`. Fourth one = `$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 4 "volume_4"
3 1 "volume_1"`. So, I have four outputs rather than three ones and also they are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so a wide aproximation to your needs could be:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path


regex = re.compile(r'\d\s\d\s\"volume_\d\"') # X X "volume_N"

def process_files(folder_path, n_iteration):
    txt_folder = Path(folder_path).rglob('*.txt')
    files = [x for x in txt_folder]

    for file_name in files:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            new_content = []
            current_iteration = n_iteration
            lines = f.readlines()
            for text_line in lines:
                if regex.match(text_line):
                    new_content.extend(new_volume_lines(current_iteration))
                    current_iteration += 1
                else:
                    new_content.append(text_line)
            f.close()

        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            for new_line in new_content:
                f.write(new_line)
            f.close()


def new_volume_lines(current_iteration):
    return [
        '3 {0} \"volume_{0}\"\n'.format(i + 1) for i in range(current_iteration)
    ]
```

Run example, let's say we have a txt at "./path/to/folder"

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 1 "volume_1"
$EndPhysicalNames
```

If we run:

```py
process_files('./path/to/folder', 3)
```

the file will end up like this:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
3 1 "volume_1"
3 2 "volume_2"
3 3 "volume_3"
$EndPhysicalNames
```

Comment: Dear @Manu, I do appreciate you for giving time to my problem. I have a question. What should I write in front of the last `for`? It should be the last `for` condition in my first code?

Comment: ok, I'm updating the answer to a complete-working solution

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.